# How to correlate service instances in biztlk queries?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a solution where I receive a message over a two way receive port, which an orchestration subscribes to.  The orchestration then calls a web service and returns a translated form of the web service response to the receive port.

If I run a completed service instances query in the BizTalk administration console I can see the receive ports receive pipeline, the orchestration, the web service transmit and receive, and the receive ports send pipeline all completed.   From the results of that query it is not possible to correlate each service instance together.  I can correlate the receive pipeline and send pipeline of the receive location because they have the same service instance, but I can't tell which orchestration service instance and which web service instance correlate to those...

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you want, but if you right click the orchestration service instance and select "Message Flow", find the outbound message that calls the web service and click on the pipeline link, that will give you the message flow for that service (the pipeline), which includes the service id.

- Right click orchestration, select "Message Flow".

[image]

- Click on the link to the send part of your web query.

[image]

This will give you the service details (the pipeline)